# Retrofit2 Code 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to do a POST, but its returning me a error :

> com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use
>   JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column
>   1 path $

My Call:

```
@POST("BuscaPontos")
Call<PontuacaoModel> postPontuacao(@Body PontuacaoModel model);
```

And my Webservice consum:

```
 try
    {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL_BUSCAR_CIDADE)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .build();
        PontuacaoModel model = new PontuacaoModel();

        model.setNome("Juina");
        model.setEstado("Mato Grosso");

        CallService.Pontuacao callService = retrofit.create(CallService.Pontuacao.class);
        Call<PontuacaoModel> requestService = callService.postPontuacao(model);
        requestService.enqueue(new Callback<PontuacaoModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PontuacaoModel> call, Response<PontuacaoModel> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    String i = response.message().toString();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PontuacaoModel> call, Throwable t) {
                String i = t.toString();
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Whats is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a line in your code where you add client during initializing retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL_BUSCAR_CIDADE)
            .client() // add a client instance here, e.g. OkHttpClient
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue with your response from server, that may not be correct format. Please install a tool called postman [form here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?utm_source=gmail).

Use this tool to check whether the response is correct before do some coding.